# iOS - UITableView delegate not being set?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

The UITableView object I have in my storyboard theoretically should have its delegate set, but it does not. I dragged the UITableView object from storyboard into the header and added it as an IBOutlet property and synthesized it. However, I checked and **only the data source method is being called**. So something seems to be wrong with the way I'm implementing the main delegate protocol. As you can see in the images below, I seem to be doing everything standardly? But the delegate is not being set still! Thoughts?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

Comment: Can you paste related codes here? Your code is hard to read in printscreen.

Comment: Are you sure about the default prototype cell  (default cell) available in the table view?

Comment: @Ganapathy how do I check that?

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason your solution is not working is because you are using a TableView inside of a UiViewController instead of a UiTableViewController. I had this same issue a while back. Here is what I did. Create an IBOutlet to the header file and synthesize it in the implementation file (I believe you have already completed this step). Go back to the storyboard. `control + click` on your table view and drag the connector to the view controller (the yellow circle with the white box). Select *datasource*. Repeat this step again and instead of selecting datasource select *delegate*. In the menu on the right-hand side you should be able to see your outlets if it is set up correctly. This should fix your delegate problems.

See the screenshot from my example below:

[image]

Comment: So I'm supposed to create a UITableViewController in addition to the UITableView? Any idea why when I can't connect the table view with the view controller as you described?

Comment: @JakeByman You don't need a UITableViewController now. You should be able to connect your UIViewController as described.

Comment: @JakeByman, Once you `ctr + click` and setup your datasource and delegate as described above I would remove `self.mainTableView.delegate = self;` and `self.mainTableView.dataSource = self;` from your implementation file.

Comment: No luck! I removed the lines, connected the view controller to the table view as you described, and the method still isn't being called! My outlets even look the same as yours. Grr...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your numberOfRows method (for better debugging).

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int rows = [allParties count];
    NSLog(@"number of rows: %d", rows);
    return rows;
}
```

If you're returning 0, it won't work.

Also in the future, please paste your code instead of taking screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

You have put a log in both `numberOfRowsInSection:` which is being called but not the one in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` which shows that no cells are being created for your table. You simply are returning 0 as number of rows for the table. Check for that.

And the delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will be called when you select a row, but for that, you have to have a row first in your table.