# Swift - Override functions in UIViewController vs UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

When I use the UITableViewController to create a tableView, you get a lot of override functions, but when you use a regular UIViewController you get an error when using these same override functions and you are forced to change them to regular functions. I believe this is why my core data won't load into my cells, and tried to use the viewDidLoad function to get my data to load.

I know my code should work since all I'm trying to do is transfer all my code from a UITableViewController to a UIViewController, and my code worked in my UITableViewController.

My effort so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Configure the cell...

        let CellID:NSString = "CELL"

        var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell

        if let ip = indexPath as Optional {

            var data:NSManagedObject = myList[ip.row] as NSManagedObject
            cell.textLabel!.text = data.valueForKeyPath("username") as? String
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Are the override functions the reason my cells are empty, or are there other aspects when using a regular UIViewController to show a tableView?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You have to add `UITableViewDelegate` to the class in order to access the delegate methods, ex:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
```

After adding the `UITableViewDelegate` to the class, your `UITableView` delegate functions should auto-complete.

Also, make sure to set the `UITableView`'s delegate to `self` in order to have the delegate methods populate the table.

(2) Right now, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is *within* your `viewDidLoad`. Move it so it's not contained within any other method.

Comment: I have added the UITableViewDelegate, as I said the app runs, it just doesn't populate the table. I have also tried with the cellForRowAtIndexPath function outside the viewDidLoad, but that didn't work. As for setting the delegate to "self" I'm not quite sure what you mean, so I can't answer to that. But as I said, all I have done is really just transferred my code from a tableViewController to a viewController, added the UITableViewDelegate and deleted the "override" in front of some functions.

Comment: @frank21 1. You need the "override". Now that you've added UITableViewDelegate, try typing the tableview delegate functions out again. They should autocomplete to include the override.

Comment: 2. You'll need to set the tableview's delegate to self, either programmatically (i.e. `self.tableView.delegate = self`) or with the interface builder, ex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19216613/2274694