# Blank picker view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am pretty new to programming and I am trying to insert a picker view.  I think my code is right, but when I build the app it is blank.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class LookingController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var iama=["dude","lady"]

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) ->Int{
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) ->Int {
        return iama.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int)->String!{
        return iama[row]
    }
}
```

Any suggestions??

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: (1) Make sure you've set the picker view's delegate (ex. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19216613/2274694) (2) I think your picker view functions should be preceded by override

Comment: I have the delegate set, but I left out dataSource, because it crashes the app every time I set it.

Comment: And it might crash when you try to set the data source but don't add UIPickerViewDataSource to the class

Comment: It gives an error, saying "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Comment: Oh, shoot. I was wrong about override with regards to UIPickerView. It's not needed. But you need to set the data source. What sort of error were you getting?

Comment: 2014-12-25 10:03:43.804 h2[31227:1361219] -[UIViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7967ba30
2014-12-25 10:03:43.817 h2[31227:1361219] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7967ba30'

Comment: OK, that error probably means that you're using the function on a general UIViewController instance and not the subclass you've created. Perhaps try changing your view controller's class in the interface from UIViewController to the specific view controller subclass.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to add pickerView into your view so follow this step.

Go to the Storyboard, drag a Picker View from the Object Library to the top of the View Controller inside the Storyboard.

The Storyboard should look like this.

[image]

The Picker View must conform to the UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate protocol. Ctrl-click the Picker View and drag from the dataSource Outlet to the View Controller in the Document Outline. Repeat this step for the delegate Outlet.

[image]

from the reference : http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/picker-view-tutorial-ios8-swift

May be this will help you.